# connect to azure Synapse via AAD authentication in Tableau

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-synapse, tableau-desktop

We are trying to connect to Synapse from Tableau via AAD authentication, but getting the following error (screenshot) despite I am the AAD owner and I have the owner permission in database.  Is there any configuration we need to do in AAD etc?. any pointers would be really helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Enter the correct details as below:

[image]

You can get server name from properties od synapse workspace as below just copy and paste them in a connection window:

[image]

make sure your AAD admin set on your workspace:

[image]

**connected successfully**

[image]